# How do I count the number of occurrences of the character in an application using PyQt

Tags: pyqt

[Create an application using PyQt that reads a string and a character from the user and count the number of occurrences of the character in the string. The count should be case-insensitive. In other words, if ‘i’ is entered as the character then both capital letter ‘I’ and small letter ‘i’ in the
string should be counted (see sample output given below). The application interface should look similar to the example provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZfgB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer very similar to the photo try it out.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Dialog,self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Dialog")
        self.groupBox=QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Count characters")
        self.layout=QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.setStyleSheet("QGroupBox,QLabel,QPushButton{font-weight:bold}")
        groupBoxLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.groupBox.setLayout(groupBoxLayout)
        groupBoxLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Step 1: Enter a string:"))
        self.lineEdit1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        groupBoxLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit1)
        groupBoxLayout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel("Step 2: Enter a character:"))
        self.lineEdit2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit2.setFixedWidth(100)
        groupBoxLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit2)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Count the characters")
        groupBoxLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.label=QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font-weight:normal")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.show()

    def onClicked(self):
        string = self.lineEdit1.text().lower()
        char = self.lineEdit2.text().lower()
        count = string.count(char)
        self.label.setText("Number of occurences: "+str(count))

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    dialog = Dialog()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```